# How to drop packets to closed ports instead of reject?

Tags: 14.04, iptables

When i connecting to closed port i'm getting 'Connection refused'. I wan't to disable sending of this response in Ubuntu 14.04.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with iptables , DROP vs REJECT.

Syntax

> iptables -option [Chain] [Rule] -j [Target]

Reject

```
iptables -P INPUT REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Drop

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

NOTE: `-j` is NOT USED with the -P option, see iptables documentation before editing please - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables#Disabling_the_firewall

Example using port 22 (here we use a -j )

REJECT

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --dport 22 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Or with DROP

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --dport 22 -j DROP
```

IMO Reject is preferred to Drop

Drop is NOT more secure then Reject (despite what "Shields up" might say).

- Crackers will not honor the "time out", so it really does not slow down crackers in any way.
- Drop tells/reveals crackers your IP address is present due to the lack of a response.
- Take a look at tools such as nmap and map test your computers on your LAN. https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html

See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

and http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject

If you need help debugging iptables, please post your entire set of rules as both the syntax and the order of the rules are critical.

Comment: @heemayl - The -j is not used with the -P option, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables#Disabling_the_firewall . I added some additional example using port 22 , and in that case yes you need a -j

Comment: Ooops, my bad..i thought it was `-A` :)

Comment: @heemayl It is alright, iptables, although not too difficult to understand the basics (assuming one has a solid foundation in networking), can get complicated fast, especially with people who write long scripts with lots of variables and custom tables, and it is easy to make a "simple" syntax error.